Keyboard shortcut to open Edge with different profiles
On Windows, I could press Win+2 to open Edge with my Work profile, and Win+3 to open Edge with my Personal profile (2 and 3 were just the positions the launchers took in the application bar at the bottom of the desk). If one of those profiles was already open, the corresponding keyboard shortcut would just focus on its window.
I am now trying to configure my Linux Mint XFCE to do the same. I went on the Keyboard Shortcuts page and

microsoft-edge --profile-directory="..." doesn't work, as it opens a new instance of edge each time.
wmctrl -a "edge ..." || microsoft-edge --profile-directory="..." works for Thunar, but not for Edge, as it turns out Edge windows are not named in a very straightforward way (they take the name of the tab that's currently open or something like that).

(also, this second option only does anything if I put it into a separate script file and have the keyboard shortcut call that file, which is annyoing, but whatever).
Claude suggested using something like
pid=$(pgrep -f "microsoft-edge --profile-directory=Default")
if [ -n "$pid" ]; then
    wmctrl -a "$(wmctrl -lp | awk -vpid="$pid" '$3==pid {print $1; exit}')"
else
    microsoft-edge --profile-directory="Default"
fi

and this still doesn't work (it always opens a new instance, failing to recognize previous ones).
Are there any simple solutions for this?
